A trigonometric maximum problem involving trigonometric constraints
Let $a,b,c,\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\alpha+\beta<2\pi$. Prove that if and only if
$$\frac{\sin\alpha}{a\sqrt{b^2+c^2-2bc\cos\alpha}}=\frac {\sin\beta}{b\sqrt{a^2+c^2-2ac\cos\beta}}=-\frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{c\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\alpha+\beta)}}\quad \tag{*}$$
then
$$f(\alpha,\beta)=\sqrt{b^2+c^2-2bc\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{a^2+c^2-2ac\cos\beta}+\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\alpha+\beta)}\tag{**}$$
obtains the maximum value.
I know that we can  get $(*)$ by letting $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta}=0$ using $(**)$.
But I want to know if there is a way to solve this problem using only unary functions or inequalities and not partial derivatives.
